# Why can't I specify a file location from media folder with pandas in django?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to get pandas to read a file from the media folder as `read_excel()`.
This is what I've tried:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Benchmark
import pandas as pd

# Create your views here.

def main_view(request):
    file = pd.read_excel('media/uploads/benchmarks/benchmarks_for_website.xlsx', index_col=0)
    context = {
        'df': file.to_html()
    }
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

It compiles, but when I try to access the html page in the browser this is the error that appears:

> FileNotFoundError at /benchmarks/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'media/uploads/benchmarks/benchmarks_for_website.xlsx'

What am I doing wrong? Also, I have the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/project/media'
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a day of further trying, I decided to test out putting the actual website url before the `media` bit. So in the end this is how it looks:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Benchmark
import pandas as pd

# Create your views here.

def main_view(request):
    file = pd.read_excel('https://url.com/media/uploads/benchmarks/benchmarks_for_website.xlsx', index_col=0)
    context = {
        'df': file.to_html()
    }
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

I'm guessing this isn't the "correct" way of doing it, but it worked for me. Please feel free to comment a better solution to this!